# Keras: CNN multiclass classifier

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, convolution

After starting with the official binary classification example of Keras (see [here](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/0830affa1f7f19fd47b06d4cf89ed44d)), I'm implementing a multiclass classifier with Tensorflow as backend. 
In this example, there are two classes (dog/cat), I've now 50 classes, and the data is stored the same way in folders.

When training, the loss won't go down and the accuracy won't go up. 
I've changed the last layer which used a `sigmoid` function to use the `softmax`, changed `binary_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy`, and changed the `class_mode` to `categorical`.

Here is my code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
import keras.optimizers



optimizer = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 224, 224

train_data_dir = 'images/train'
validation_data_dir = 'images/val'
nb_train_samples = 209222
nb_validation_samples = 40000
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))



model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('weights.h5')
```

Any idea on where I might be wrong ? 
Any input will be much appreciated !

EDIT:
as asked by @RobertValencia, here are the beginning of the latest training logs:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.7.5 locally
Found 3517 images belonging to 50 classes.
<keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator object at 0x7fd1d4515c10>
Found 2451 images belonging to 50 classes.
Epoch 1/50
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE3 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:910] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GRID K520
major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.797
pciBusID 0000:00:03.0
Total memory: 3.94GiB
Free memory: 3.91GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GRID K520, pci bus id: 0000:00:03.0)
 8098/13076 [=================>............] - ETA: 564s - loss: 15.6869 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0267
```

Comment: What's up with your optimizer settings? Why such a small momentum and why disable nesterov momentum?

Comment: @nemo thanks, copied the wrong optimize here. Just edited. But I'm having this issue with `optimizer = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)`  (as edited on the post)

Comment: Do you have the appropriate directory structure for each class? Make sure that the (x,y) pairs generated by the training generator are correct (try calling `next()` on the train generator and look at the results).

Comment: Can you try `categorical_accuracy` instead of `accuracy` for your metrics?

Comment: @nemo it seems like it. I have the exact same structure as in the example on keras.io (with more classes of course)
@RobertValencia ok, just started a new training with `categorical_accuracy`

Comment: @RobertValencia doesn't seem to be changing much from the results I had

Comment: @GrahamSlick can you show us your training logs?

Comment: @RobertValencia just added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Considering the number of classes you need to differentiate, perhaps increasing the complexity of the model, as well as using a different optimizer, could yield better results. Try using this model, which is partially based on the VGG-16 CNN architecture, but not as complex:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='softmax'))

optimizer = Nadam(lr=0.002,
                  beta_1=0.9,
                  beta_2=0.999,
                  epsilon=1e-08,
                  schedule_decay=0.004)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

If you get better results, I suggest looking into the VGG-16 model:

1. https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/applications/vgg16.py or
2. https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3 (includes zero-padding and dropout layers)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, but it seems like the kind of thing that could take the model from 80% accuracy to 95%, but not from 3% to 95. But I'll definitely try it in a few hours and let you know

Comment: Okay. Let us know if you get better results. I am also curious about its outcome.